# Upload Button created with AjaxUpload behaves strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax-upload

question is bit different than other questions regarding this. I had a similar issue as [jQuery AjaxUpload, have to click button twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134762/jquery-ajaxupload-have-to-click-button-twice) but I managed to fix it with my workaround. Button comes perfectly. But now issue is, when I click that button after dragging my mouse when coming from top or the left of the button, it doesn't work, but if i drag my mouse from other side, it works fine.
In short, when coming from top to that button, button gets hovered, not the hidden file selector created by ajax upload.

[image: while not taking mouse on that button from top]

[image: When taking move on that button from top or left]

In first image, I took mouse pointer from side of the button and i get option to choose file. But as shown in other image, I took mouse pointer from top of the button and button is hovered.

Here is my button code:

```
<input type="button" value="Upload Image" class="imgUploadBtn" />
```

My JS snippet:

```
function uploadAndGetImgUrl(tsource,status) {
    new AjaxUpload(tsource,{
        action: 'imageUpload.php',
        name: 'uploadfile',
        data: {},
        onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){
                    // extension is not allowed
                    status.text('Only Images are Allowed');
                    return false;
                }
                status.text('Uploading...');
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response){
            //On completion clear the status
            status.text('');
            $('#idSpclImgLink').val(response);
            $('#idImgLink').val(response);
        }
    });
}

$(document).live("imgAttach",function() {
    alert("Want something Added");
    uploadAndGetImgUrl($('.imgUploadBtn'),$('#idStatus'));
});
```

I checked ajaxupload.3.5.js but and found it does some process while hovering and uses left and top offsets to retain hover effect. But I couldn't fix a fix yet for that. Any idea why is this happening?

PS: I use chrome. I also checked in Firefox and same behavior.

Comment: Can you create a full example at jsfiddle.net. please? A "video" says more than one million words.

Comment: @reporter i cannot provide full code because it is a office code and I may not have the privilege to share the whole code. I'll see if I can make a video.

Comment: Then replacae the offcial values with dummy values. We just interested in the html source code that the browser received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly an solution to general problem but for my case, I simply changed 2 lines and works for my scenario.

Change line number 368 and 369 to

```
if ((c.x >= box.left-5) && (c.x <= box.right) && 
        (c.y >= box.top-10) && (c.y <= box.bottom)){
```

It will apparently work.

Answer (score 1):

open the plugin file for ajaxupload..

in the function where the mousemove event handler is being defined, find the comment:
// mouse left the button

Update the next line to 
over = true;

Comment: That partially solved the issue but focus is bit towards down side. I mean little part of top button still doesn't work while little part after bottom of button works!